# What is the swift equivalent of objc's @class?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Objective c can use class forwarding to tell the compiler a class will exist at run time.

`@class ABC`

Is there an equivalent concept in swift?

Comment: No need for that in Swift.

Comment: you don't need that in Swift.

Comment: I totally need that in swift so I can make the compiler reference a class that isn't defined in the current module.  But since swift doesn't have it, I have no choice but to use Objective-c for this part.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.